# Save image from url in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to save a image from following link. I've used cURL library and file_put_contents() function with no success. When I run the script, a HTTP error happens and the image is not saved.
The link is:
`http://pocanga.cptec.inpe.br/repositorio5/goes12/goes12_web/no_realcada_alta/2012/01/S11219780_201201010015.jpg`

```
$outputPath = "img/image.jpg";
file_put_contents($outputPath, file_get_contents($link));
```

Maybe `file_get_contents()` unfortunatelly doesn't accept url subdomain.

Comment: Can you give us all the code ? What is the error ? We don't know how to help you if we don't know what is wrong. We're not magician.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is not `cURL`. What HTTP error are you getting? As far as I can see the image loads really slowly - perhaps you're getting a timeout?

Comment: Yes, I can provide all the code.
    <?php
    $link = "http://pocanga.cptec.inpe.br/repositorio5/goes12/goes12_web/no_realcada_alta/2012/01/S11219780_201201010015.jpg";
    $outputPath = "img/image.jpg";
    file_put_contents($outputPath, file_get_contents($link));
    ?>

Comment: @Renan: Look at my answer below. I fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

The `header` information did the trick. Otherwise it was putting a blank image.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"
     )
));

$url = 'http://pocanga.cptec.inpe.br/repositorio5/goes12/goes12_web/no_realcada_alta/2012/01/S11219780_201201010015.jpg';
$img = 'img.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context));
```